# how to get subject with and or condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select distinct a1.id
from m a1, m a2
on a1.Id = a2.Id
where a1.sub = 'physics' and a2.sub <> 'chem';
```

I want a student who' has taken physics but not chem?

giving me wrong result?

any inputs?

Comment: It might help if you describe your database schema for us

Comment: Remove the distinct keyword and try again

Answer (score 4):

By using `not exists` :

```
select * 
from m a1
where a1.sub = 'physics'  
and not exists (select 1 from m where id = a1.id and sub = 'chem')
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of a set-within-sets query.  Here is a solution using `group by` and `having`:

```
select a.id
from m a
group by a.id
having sum(a.sub = 'physics') > 0 and
       sum(a.sub = 'chem') = 0;
```

The expression `sum(a.sub = 'physics')` counts the number of rows that are for "physics".  The `> 0` says that at least one must be present.  Similarly, the second clause says there are no rows with "chem".

The advantage of this approach is that you can easily generalize it.  For instance, to include a requirement for biology:

```
from m a
group by a.id
having sum(a.sub = 'physics') > 0 and
       sum(a.sub = 'bio') > 0 and
       sum(a.sub = 'chem') = 0;
```

Comment: I think you missed case within sum it should be like this.

`select a.id
from m a
group by a.id
having sum(case when a.sub = 'physics' then 1 else 0) > 0 and
       sum(case when a.sub = 'chem' then 1 else 0) = 0;`

Comment: @RegisteredUser . . . The `case` statement is not needed for MySQL.  Boolean evaluations are treated as integers, with 0 for false and 1 for true.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query

```
SELECT  distinct m.id 
FROM from table_name m 
WHERE
    m.a1 like 'physics' 
    and m.a2 <>'chem';
```